# Restangular GET request with data

Tags: angularjs, get, parse-platform, restangular

Is there a way to send a GET request with data using Restangular? I'm using Parse as a backend for my AngularJS app and to login it requires a GET with data:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ..." \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ..." \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'username=cooldude6' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=p_n7!-e8' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

From: https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login

I've tried a `customOperation` but it doesn't send the data

```
var login = Restangular.all('login');
login.customOperation('get', '', {}, {}, {username: 'user'}); // ignore encoding for now
```

This just sends a GET request to /login but without any data.

Comment: What is the problem with ```.get({username: 'cooldude6'})``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the Parse.com documentation. I thought the credentials had to be send as body of the request because of the -G in the curl command. But apparently they need to be send as normal parameters.